# Using Codeigniter Payments

Tags: codeigniter

How to properly use the `$this->payments->payment_action();` function?

All I get is this:

```
object(stdClass)#137 (5) {
  ["type"]=&gt;
  string(14) "local_response"
  ["status"]=&gt;
  string(7) "failure"
  ["response_code"]=&gt;
  string(3) "000"
  ["response_message"]=&gt;
  string(32) "The method called does not exist"
  ["details"]=&gt;
  string(27) "No further details provided"
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this?

Comment: It's like this:

$response = $this->payments->payment_action('gateway_name', $params);

I don't know what I should put in `$params`

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

As per the question, You are receiving some objects.

For ex: Here i'm just printing the object content. If you ant to store in db, then you can do with `$obj`.

```
$obj = $this->payments->payment_action();    
echo "Type = ".$obj->type;
echo "Status= ".$obj->status;
echo "Response code= ".$obj->response_code;
echo "Response Message= ".$obj->response_message;
echo "Details= ".$obj->details;
```